# Spring @Transactional для родительского класса, который не является бином

Tags: java, spring, transaction, spring-transaction

Насколько я понимаю аннотация `@Transactional` имеет смысл и работает, только тогда когда она относится к какому-либо спринг бину. Например, рассмотрим вот такой код:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class EmailService implements IEmailService {

   @Override
   public String sendEmail() {
       ....
   }
}
```

Если убрать из данного примера `@Service` (то же самое для `@Component` и `@Repository`), то `@Transactional` автоматически теряет смысл, тк собственно не будет создан бин для которого `@Transactional` могла бы быть применена.

Но мне не понятен вот такой следующий пример. Скажем, у нас есть класс-родитель и классы-дети.
Класс-родитель не является спринг бином, а классы-дети - уже определены как бины (через `@Service`).

```
@Service
public class OldEmailService extends BaseEmailService {
     public RobotEmailService() {
          super("old")
     }
}

@Service
public class NewEmailService extends BaseEmailService {
     public ExtraEmailService() {
          super("new")
     }
}

@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BaseEmailService implements IEmailService {

  private final String tableName;

   @Override
   public String sendEmail() {
       // вычисления с tableName
   }
}
```

Классы-дети `OldEmailService` и `NewEmailService` не переопределяют метод `sendEmail()` класса-родителя. Также обратите внимание, что `@Transactional` здесь расположена над классом не обозначенным как бин.
Если в дальнейшем мы будем использовать бины `oldEmailService` и `newEmailService`, и вызовем в данных бинах метод `sendEmail()` из родительского-класса, то будет ли вызов такого метода транзакционным?

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SenderService implements ISenderService {
    private final IEmailService oldEmailService;
    private final IEmailService newEmailService;

    @Override
    public String doSomeStaff() {
        if (...) {
            // будет ли вызов транзакционным?
            oldEmailService.sendEmail();
        } else {
            // будет ли вызов транзакционным?
            newEmailService.sendEmail();
        }
    }
}
```

Можно ли так делать? Или нужно было явно пометить классы `OldEmailService` и `NewEmailService` как `@Transactional`, убрав её из класса-родителя?

Comment: Да, можно. Эта аннотация помечена как @Inherited, следовательно она "будет видна" во всех наследуемых классах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оформлю ответ сам раз никто не сформулировал. Как отметил [Serodv](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/261878/serodv) в своём комментарии к вопросу

> Да, можно. Эта аннотация помечена как @Inherited, следовательно она
> "будет видна" во всех наследуемых классах.

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface Transactional {
...
}
```

Документацию на наследуемую аннотацию можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html), документацию на `Transactional` [тут](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html).